# Difference between English and English International for Windows 10 .ISO?

Tags: windows-10, iso-image, language, english

I've been researching into Windows 10 recently. On the .ISO download page, one of the choices to make is which language you want Windows to be in. There are two English choices: English and English International. I have tried to find information on the difference between these, but to no avail. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Essentially, they are the same.

The International version contains localized English keyboard languages (like United Kingdom, Australia, etc.).

While the en-US (English) only contains the minimum of English-based languages.

Comment: Well, they're not really the same. One is entirely US-centric, like they invented the language. The other acknowledges that may not in fact be so.

Comment: @Tetsujin Indeed you are 100% correct.  ["The International English  includes various localized English Languages which Windows should support grammatically, like  AU, UK, Jamaica, Trinidad etc. It should also support the Keyboard layout, as there are International Keyboards."](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/24007c7d-ad5b-40f8-bec5-241d4bb55261/difference-windows-10-enterprise-english-enterprise-english-international?forum=win10itprosetup)

Comment: American English is but a quasi-dialect of English.

Comment: The Windows English ISO that I'm [currently downloading](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) is 4,38 GB. The Windows English International ISO is 4,24GB. How does removing language support increase the ISO size?

Comment: It's English and Simplified English

Comment: @minhng99 Lol what a burn! Also wth is isn't the British English version called "English" and the US version called "American English".

Comment: @KarlMorrison Don't even get me started on that one...

Comment: For some reason, however, the "International" version does not include the US English language, only "English (United Kingdom)" can be selected in the installer.  So they are actually complementary "US" and "non-US English".  I'd wish I could have "US English but with 24 hour and other formats" without hassle...

Answer (score 10):

UK one has colour instead of color and favourites in place of favorites, that's it really.... Keyboards, time and date, measures systems these are THE same in both and in separate setting of region NOT language (when you install windows you can choose any region on any language version) My recommendation is stick to US version since UK one needs separate upgrades and it's problematic later on...

Comment: There are also time & date differences. In the international version, the default time zone is different, the clock has 24 instead of 12h and the week starts on Monday, not Sunday. I believe there is also a difference in units (metric vs imperial and currency differences).
Now, all of these settings are available in both variants, it's just that the defaults are different. They can always be changed.

Comment: Is there a setting to switch "colour" to "color" in the International ISO?